# What is the scope of javascript callback and anonymous functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, riak

I have written the following code using node.js and [riak-js](http://riakjs.org).  I have a recursive function `walk` that should be a list of JSON documents, but instead returns an empty list... why? how to fix?

```
require('riak-js');

var walk = function(bucket, key, list){ 
  if(list == undefined){
    var list = new Array();
  } 
  db.get(bucket, key)(function(doc, meta){     
     list.push(doc);
     if(meta.links.length > 0 && meta.links[0].tag == 'child'){
       walk(bucket, meta.links[0].key, list);
     }   
  });
  return list; 
}

familytree = walk('smith', 'walter', []);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Based on the guide, I think your syntax is off.  It should be `db.get(bucket, key, function(doc, meta)`...

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen is right. Your syntax for `db.get` is wrong.

Comment: actually my syntax is correct for the version of riak-js I'm using (v0.2.2) - if you look at the guide, you'll see that it says "Note: This guide is only applicable to riak-js 0.3.0"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get an empty array because `db.get()` is asynchronous. It returns immediately without waiting for the callback to be invoked. Therefore when the interpretor reaches the `return list` statement, `list` is still an empty array.

It is a fundamental concept in Node.js (and even in browser scripting) that everything is asynchronous (non-blocking).